# Applying Fundamental Theorem of calculus to stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I would like to know if the fundamental theorem of calculus is applicable to stochastic integrals? I have seen a recent working in a textbook where the author did the following

$$
y(t)=\int_0^te^{\theta S}dW_s
$$
$$
dy(t)=e^{\theta t}dW_t
$$

And I am not sure how did he go from the first line to the second.

Comment: The second line is just another notation for the first line.There is nothing to be  proved here.

Comment: @geetha290krm wasn't the second line achieved from differentiating the first line?

Comment: No. Stochastic integrals are not differentiable in the classical sense. Google “Itô calculus”